# window.open causes main window to exit full screen mode. Is there a workaround?

Tags: javascript

I have a main window,which on click of a button makes the window fullscreen. I have used document.documentElement.requestFullscreen() for this and it works. Now there is another button on which I need to open a pop out window for which I have used window.open() API. The problem is that as soon as window.open is executed it causes the main window to exit full screen mode automatically.

I tried to call requestFullscreen() on "onload" of popped out window but this gives error saying that requestFullscreen can not be called without user event.

```
//Code to open pop up
window.open('http://www.google.com', 'Tab','toolbar=no,menubar=no')
```

What can be done so that my main window remains in full screen mode even after using window.open method?

Comment: What this does is tell the BROWSER to go full screen, not the current page/window/tab. It's all or nothing, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you please elaborate all or nothing? I mean it is ok for me if the current window is in fullscreen mode and the popped out windows also open on full screen mode.

Comment: The entire browser is in full-screen mode. That means all windows and tabs are full-screen. If anything changes the full-screen state, the entire browser returns to windowed mode.